# Heirloom mailx doesn't display UTF-8 characters

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, mailx

I'm using Heirloom mailx 12.5-2.

When I'm receiving a mail with characters like "ä", "ö" or "ü" mailx can't display these and just shows "�".

The mails charset is "iso-8859-1".
I already tried to set the options "ttycharset", "sendcharsets" to "iso-8859-1" or "UTF-8", but it doesn't help.
Also the options "print-all-chars", "encoding" or "reply-in-same-charset" don't solve the problem.

My locale and terminal are on UTF-8.

Does anyone has an other idea?

Thanx